# Number format setting change in MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, locale

I'm using CMake and MinGW compiling a larger project (`g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0`).

At the beginning I set a boost generated locale and try the formatting:

```
//Global
std::locale myLoc;

    // Init function
    std::locale newLocale(boost::locale::generator().generate("C"));
    std::locale::global(newLocale);
    std::cerr << 1.1234 << std::endl;
    myLoc = std::locale();
```

Later I want to output the number again but suddenly I have another decimal point (`,` as I'm on a German system) However the locale does not seem to be changed.

```
std::cerr << (std::locale() == myLoc) << std::endl;
std::cerr << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(1.1234) << std::endl;
std::cerr << std::use_facet<std::numpunct<char> >(std::locale()).decimal_point() << std::endl;
```

The output is:

```
1.1234
1
1,1234
.
```

So in total: Formatting works at first, locale is still the same, decimal_point still returns `.` but I get a `,`. How is this possible?

I wasn't able to reproduce this in a MWE but would be thankful for any tips how to look into this.

Comment: Smells like boost::lexical_cast uses the C locale instead of the C++ locale.  Well, that's a bug they can never fix again :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `setLocale` and `std::locale` are independent of each other.

Somewhere down my code I found a hidden `setLocale` which caused the problem. Specifically I was using a custom `gettext` implementation which requires a `setLocale` to change the language. While this is of course desirable it, as a side effect, also changes the number formatting. This is due to the fact, that there is no `LC_MESSAGES` parameter for `setLocale`.

So 2 solutions:

1. Reset the C++ locale with e.g. `std::locale::global(std::locale::classic());` or the initial call after calling `setLocale`
2. Don't use lexical_cast if you rely on the output. Example: Use boost.Locale with an explicit locale.